# how to loop through output of mongo db find query in shellscript

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, bash, jq

```
ele=$(mongo ${DATABASE_NAME} --quiet --eval 'printjson(db.'${COLLECTION_NAME'.find({"status":1},{"_id": 1, "setId": 1}).toArray())')
```

This returns
`[ { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729093"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729094"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" } ]`
Now when i want to do further processing on this data,the loop is not returning it as 2 elements,but instead 1.. How do i make it to 1 document at a time within the loop.

```
for i in "${ele[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: What output do you expect from the shell?

Comment: Each entry(document) from the table(collection) in the loop..this is returning everything as one single entry

Comment: `ele=$( <command> )` populates `ele` with one long string of data; to populate a `bash` array with the output of `<command>` you need to wrap the righthand side in an additional set of parens, eg, `ele=( $( <command> ) )`; this should split the `<command>` output on white space when determining the array elements ... but I'm guessing that may not be what you want, ie, the query appears to be generating json in which case the current assignment (`ele=$( <command> )`) is likely ok and what you really need is to use something like `jq` to parse `ele` ... ???

Comment: it would probably help if you provide a smallish sample of what the query generates and then provide an example of what you want the loop to generate; and if the query *is* generating `json` then I'd recommend you add a `json` tag to the question to expand visibility on the question; **NOTE:** I don't work with `mongo` so I'm *guessing* that `printjson()` generates a `json` structure ... ???

Comment: [ { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729093"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729094"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" } ]

Comment: this is a sample output with 2 elements...similarly there could be many..Yes adding parenthesis will not help in this case

Comment: please update the question with the additional details (sample of query output, expected output from shell loop); not everyone will read through the comments trying to piece together the whole picture; also, (important) formatting details are lost in comments

Comment: When you run in bash `ele=[ { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729093"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729094"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" } ]` then you get an error. So, still the same question, what do you expect as output from mongo shell?

Comment: consider processing your data in a `while` loop, ie `mongo cmd ..... | while IFS="\n" read line ; do echo processing $line data here ; done` . There will be many examples here on S.O., but they may be difficult to find. maybe search for `[bash] isql while` Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) tag has been included, here's a script showing the kind of thing you could do using jq.

The main problem from the JSON-processing point of view is that your sample is not actually JSON.
If you could get mongo to give you JSON, then things would be much more straightforward.

In any case, in the following, we first convert your pseuso-JSON to valid JSON, using a bespoke jq function, here named `ObjectId`.

With your example, the following script produces the output shown below it:

```
#!/bin/bash

mongo='[ { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729093"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" }, 
         { "_id" : ObjectId("64a3f08660a51f2848729094"), "setId" : "64a3f08560a51f2848729092" } ]'

function itemize {
  jq -nc "
  def ObjectId(s): {ObjectId: s};

  $mongo
  | .[]"
}

while read -r object ; do
    echo "$object"
done < <(itemize)
```

Output:

```
{"_id":{"ObjectId":"64a3f08660a51f2848729093"},"setId":"64a3f08560a51f2848729092"}
{"_id":{"ObjectId":"64a3f08660a51f2848729094"},"setId":"64a3f08560a51f2848729092"}
```

Comment: Will try this out